# Spring boot not serving static content returns a 404 not found

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Spring boot configuration.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }
    ...
   }
```

Where I placed the necessary static content

[image]

And accessing it through my jsp

```
<link href="./resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

it returns a 404 not found. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Boot serves static resources from directories like `/static`, `/public` or `/resources`. So you could put your resources into `src/main/resources/static`.

If you have a resource `src/main/resources/static/css/bootstrap.min.css` you can access it via

```
<link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

See also the [Reference Guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content).